# How to track installs from App Store (iOS App) with Firebase Analytics?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, sdk, google-ads-api

The marketing area of my company wants to create an installation campaign of an iOS app in google ads, however we can only measure the first_open event. Is there a way to directly measure app downloads in firebase analytics? to then import this event to the google ads platform

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution?

Comment: @LiborZapletal Does firebase provides number of iOS app install using particular dynamic link?